# Functionality like iOS's keyboard shortcut functionality

Tags: macos, ios, keyboard

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of another question because naming the functionality in iOS that enables the user to type in a shortcut (like "omy") and have it expand to a whole phrase (like "on my way") as "Shortcuts" was a bad idea, in my opinion.

I'd like to have a way to type in a shortcut and have it expand to a whole phrase, just as one can do so in iOS. Is there any native way to do that? Or would I have to write an Apple Script of some sort? I know of an application called, "[Typinator](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/)" that does this, but I don't like the idea of spending money if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **System Preferences**, go to **Language & Text** and hit the **Text** tab. The left column is essentially the same as what Shortcuts are in iOS' settings. This has the added advantage of being able to use Emoji.
[image: System Preferences > Language & Text > Text]

Answer (score 2):

There are good apps that allow you to set up text expansion with a nice GUI. This is the one I have used and liked:

### [Dash Expander](http://kapeli.com/dashexpander/)

*[Mac App Store Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dashexpander/id458867049?ls=1&mt=12)*

Dash Expander handles text expansion very well. I have used it and it works well. The free version:

> "...will nag and annoy you every now and then, in order to purchase."

I haven't found these to be that obtrusive. However, as of writing the full version is just $1.99. This also has the ability to set variables. For example, you can set up a boiler-plate thank you note, and just set variables in there that you quickly go through and change to personalize for the recipient.

Comment: It's interesting that I never found this app on my own; I actually use Dash (made by the people that make Dash Expander).